# Processing JSP From Within Java Code

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp

Does anyone know if it's possible to process a JSP page from within Java code and get the resulting HTML string?

I'm working on a project that has a Spring Boot application.  One of the requirements is to have an end point that returns JSON.  The JSON is suppose to contain one or more properties that contain HTML strings that were generated by JSP templates.  The JSON will contain other other properties as well.

I've done some research and I've found examples showing how to process Freemarker and Thymeleaf templates from within Java code.  However, I've been unable to find any examples showing how to do this with JSP.  Ideally we would like to use JSP as that's what our developers know and in the interest of time there would be no learning curve as opposed to if we went with Freemarker or Thymeleaf.

Has anyone out there done this before with JSP?

Comment: JSPs are compiled to Java servlets. If you're just looking for templating, I doubt you want to do that with JSPs.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, we were just looking for templating and we ultimately decided to use Thymeleaf which has worked well.